# Materialize CSS, choosing font color or family?

Tags: html, css, frameworks

I wanna put some text in orange. It is an h4, or just need  for changing its colour.

http://materializecss.com/typography.html

there'are diferent Roboto font family, but I dont know how to use it without using font-family...

Comment: How this problem is connected with a framework?

Comment: I don't understand your answer, sorry. You can select some background colors adding class blue lighten-1 for example, what about text?

Comment: @dmanso use class `orange-text` to make the text orange for that specific element. Just append `-text` to the color to make the text in that color. It clearly says so in the [documentation](http://materializecss.com/color.html)

Answer (score 0):

I you want to change the color, then:

```
<h3 class="orange">Hello world!</h4>
```

If you want to color the text as well, you can do

```
<h4 class="orange white-text">Hello world!</h4>
```

See http://materializecss.com/color.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<h4 class='text-orange text-darken-3'>TITLE</h4>
```

Comment: This causes no change to the text color of h4 elements

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your custom css.

```
.dropdown-content, .select-dropdown{
  font-family: "BT Mono bold" !important;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like css classes available in matz library as you have mentioned.

should be like this
**.blue-text text-darken-2**

for more refer in color usage section of matz.

Answer (score -1):

You must use the font-family in css file

```
h4 {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  color:orange;
}
```